# Not getting Wifi's list using NEHotspotConfigurationManager class

Tags: ios, swift, wifi, nehotspothelper

I am trying to get the wifi list, but I get a blank array every time.

I'm using below code:

```
NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.getConfiguredSSIDs { (ssidsArray) in
            print("ssidsArray.count==\(ssidsArray.count)")
            for ssid in ssidsArray {
                print("Connected ssid = ",ssid)
            }
        }
```

How to get all connected wifi's list programmatically in swift

Comment: Have you enable the Hotspot Configuration capability in Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I have already enable Hotspot configuration in Xcode and as well as apple developer portal.

Answer (score 1):

Please carefully read documentation for [getConfiguredSSIDs(completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager/2866695-getconfiguredssids) function:

> Returns the SSIDs or the names of the Wi-Fi hotspot domains **that YOUR**
>   **APP has configured** and invokes an optional completion handler.

It means that the function lists configurations that were applied by your application using [apply(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager/2866649-apply) function.

Probably [Hotspot Helper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/hotspot_helper) can do what you want but you'll need to submit a justification to Apply why you need this functionality.